# How can I get a Phonegap app to install at the same time as an App store app

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using PhoneGap (Build) to create an iOS and Android app. I have 2 versions of the app on PhoneGap, one is setup with an Apple and a Google certificate, which I use to get the ipa / apk files to send to the App & Play stores. The other is used as a staging app, and our test devices install this app from directly from PhoneGap.

I'm having an issue getting both versions of the app to install on our test Apple devices at the same time. If the App Store app is installed, the PhoneGap staging app removes it when it is installed, and vice versa.

In `config.xml` there are 2 versions with a different `widget id`. So they should appear to the device as different apps:

```
staging.myappsname.app
com.myappsname.app
```

This setup works on Android devices, how can I get iOS to see them as separate apps?

Comment: Did you adjust both config.xml files?  (in iOS: yourprojectroot/platforms/ios/yourprojectname/config.xml)?

Comment: I'm using phonegap build, so there is no platforms folder. The settings page on build has the package name as staging.myappsname.app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd forgotten about this question.

On iOS, the apps are differentiated by the signing certificate. So the staging app needs to have a separate provisioning file and key from Apple Developer Center.

The App Store provisioning file & key should be generated from a Distribution Certificate.

The "staging app" provisioning file & key should be generated from a Development certificate.